# Inconsistent query execution times using trigram indexes?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `residences`...

I installed trgm: `create extension pg_trgm;`

After adding trigram indexes to both `grp` and `name` columns using:

```
CREATE INDEX residences_name_trgm ON residences USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX residences_grp_trgm ON residences USING GIN (grp gin_trgm_ops);
```

And checking performance of a simple query... it appears that the total runtime for a query on the `name` column runs ~100x faster. **Why is this?**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM residences WHERE name ILIKE '%Sutton%';
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on residences  (cost=36.02..47.90 rows=3 width=1872) (actual time=0.390..0.720 rows=21 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((name)::text ~~ '%Sutton%'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on residences_name_trgm_gin  (cost=0.00..36.02 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.354..0.354 rows=21 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((name)::text ~~ '%Sutton%'::text)
 Total runtime: 0.814 ms
(5 rows)
```

and

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM residences WHERE grp ILIKE '%Sutton%';
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on residences  (cost=97.93..8879.41 rows=5927 width=1872) (actual time=5.516..115.634 rows=5968 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((grp)::text ~~ '%Sutton%'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on residences_grp_trgm_gin  (cost=0.00..96.45 rows=5927 width=0) (actual time=4.366..4.366 rows=5968 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((grp)::text ~~ '%Sutton%'::text)
 Total runtime: 119.779 ms
(5 rows)
```

For reference, both `name` and `grp` columns are `CHARACTER VARYING(50)`.

Futhermore... counting distinct values in each column yields:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT grp) FROM residences;
421

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM residences
7750
```

That is, the `name` column actually has ~20x more distinct values, but returns values much faster.

More information on this technique can be found on depesz's article [WAITING FOR 9.1 – FASTER LIKE/ILIKE](http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/) and another similar tutorial [on the PalominoDB blog](http://palominodb.com/blog/2011/10/12/indexing-text-columns-gist-or-gin-optimize-ilike-using-pgtrgm-postgres-91-part-1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That is, the name column actually has ~20x more distinct values, but returns values much faster.

Exactly so. An index on `name` is *more selective* than an index on `grp`, so index use is more effective.

This is confirmed by the fact that your first query, on the `name` field, the bitmap index scan on`residences_grp_trgm_gin` gets only 21 results as shown by `actual( ... rows=21 ...)` in the `explain analyze` output. On `grp` you get 5968 results.

In a bitmap index scan every heap read and re-check has a significant cost, so it makes perfect sense that finding 21 rows is going to be a lot faster than finding 5968.

BTW, please always show `select version()` and [your server configuration](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Server_Configuration), as well as anything else that's relevant from [the wiki's guide to reporting problems](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Guide_to_reporting_problems).

Comment: Thank you. Do you have tips on how I could possibly optimize?

Comment: Hard to say, I don't have much experience with trigram indexes yet. First I'd try `enable_bitmapscan = off` to see if the next-best plan chosen actually performs better and if so, look into whether I need to adjust `random_page_cost` / `cpu_tuple_cost` to guide the planner in the right direction.